# can't retrieve value from JSON results

Tags: python, json, rest, curl, backendless

I am retrieving an entry from a table with a REST call by searching by property, converting the bytes to string, then grabbing the `objectId` value from the results.

```
new_requests = Popen(['curl',
                  '-H', 'application-id: %s' % backendless_appid,
                  '-H', 'secret-key: %s' % backendless_sk,
                  '-H', 'Content-Type: application/json',
                  '-X', 'GET',
                  '-v', 'https://api.backendless.com/v1/data/Request?where=requestId%3D1'],
                 stdout=PIPE).communicate()[0]

new_requests_str = new_requests.decode(encoding='utf-8')

new_requests_objectid = json.loads(new_requests_str, strict=False)['objectId']
```

Unfortunately this results in `KeyError: 'objectId'`

`print(new_requests_str)` returns the JSON results, so the problem is `new_requests_objectid`.

```
{"offset":0,"data":[{"emailAddress":"eric@apakau.com","apiEndpoint":"http://www.yahoo.com","created":1438986033000,"requestId":"1","___class":"Request","ownerId":null,"updated":1439222409000,"objectId":"723B5AEE-5D60-E00E-FF92-ACA3B4629F00","apiSecretkey":"asdfasa","__meta":"{\"relationRemovalIds\":{},\"selectedProperties\":[\"emailAddress\",\"apiEndpoint\",\"created\",\"requestId\",\"___class\",\"ownerId\",\"updated\",\"objectId\",\"apiSecretkey\"],\"relatedObjects\":{}}"}],"nextPage":null,"totalObjects":1}
```

Comment: Try printing `new_requests_str` , what do you get?

Comment: Why are you calling the cURL binary from python? I would highly recommend that you take a look at [requests](http://python-requests.org/). _If_ you _really_ think you need cURL for some reason, take a look at [PycURL](http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: @Anand `print(new_requests)` and `print(new_requests_str)` both return nothing.

Comment: @AnandSKumar Actually, after trying again, `new_requests_str` returns the JSON results. So it seems the problem lies in `new_requests_objectid`.

Comment: Please update the question with what it returns.

Comment: @Eric check whether the returned JSON has objectId , it might not have it.

Comment: @Anand I've checked, and it's there.

Comment: Then can you update the question with an example of the result of `print` ?

Comment: @Anand Updated the question with the result of `print(new_requests_str)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `objectId` is not a direct key in the new_requests json . Instead it is a part of the dictionary in `data` list. So you would need to access it like that . Most probably it is possible for the request to return a response with multiple objects (and multiple `objectId`s ) , So I would suggest keeping them in a list , Example -

```
new_requests = Popen(['curl',
                  '-H', 'application-id: %s' % backendless_appid,
                  '-H', 'secret-key: %s' % backendless_sk,
                  '-H', 'Content-Type: application/json',
                  '-X', 'GET',
                  '-v', 'https://api.backendless.com/v1/data/Request?where=requestId%3D1'],
                 stdout=PIPE).communicate()[0]

new_requests_str = new_requests.decode(encoding='utf-8')

new_requests_objectIds = []

for data_item in json.loads(new_requests_str, strict=False)['data']:
    new_requests_objectIds.append(data_item['objectId'])
```

Comment: I see that now. Your code worked. The result is inside brackets and single quotes: `['723B5AEE-5D60-E00E-FF92-ACA3B4629F00']` How can I remove them?

Comment: Yes that is because its a list, why do you want to remove them? Are you 100% sure that you would always only have 1 data? , 1 objectId?

Comment: No, I will sometimes have more than 1 objectId. I don't have a strong background in data structures, so I will have to study lists. If it's not too hard to answer: if I get two objectIds, how would I assign them as separate variables?

Comment: No list is a good way to go, to deal with the two different objectIds in the list, you can iterate over them and deal with each one separately. If you have background in any other language like C or java or C++ , etc. Lists are like Arrays there , you can subscript them (list[0] points to the first element in list) , iterate over them using for loop, etc etc.

Comment: Thank you. Now I remember learning about arrays and subscripts (I wasn't a Computer Science major but took some intro courses on programming).